# see if string could be read the same way from both left and right using stack

Tags: c++, c, string, stack

I have recently started to learn using stack.my question is : I want to get a string from user and store it in a stack and see if this string is the same when read from left and right or not but i don't know what to do.could you please help me?
this is my program so far :

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 # define Size 100
 using namespace std;
  struct stack
 {
  int items[Size];
  int MyTop;
 };
  int Empty(stack *s)
 {
      if(s->MyTop==-1)
       return 1;
      else
       return 0;
 }
  void PushAndTest(int *Overflow,char x,stack *s)
 {
      if (s->MyTop==Size-1)
       *Overflow=1;
      else
       {
         *Overflow=0;          
         s->items[++(s->MyTop)]=x; 
       }
 }
 int PopAndTest(int *Underflow,char *x,stack *s)
 {
      if (Empty(s)!=1)
       *Underflow=1;
      else
       {      
         *x=s->items[(s->MyTop)--]; 
         *Underflow=0;    
       }
 }
  int TopAndTest(int *Underflow,char *x,stack *s)
 {
      if (s->MyTop==Size-1)
       *Underflow=1;
      else
       {
         *Underflow=0;          
         *x=s->items[(s->MyBottom)]; 
       }       
 }
 void Show(stack *s)
 {
        if(Empty(s)!=0)
            cout<<"Underflow";
        else
         {
            for(int i=0;i<=s->MyTop;i++)  
            {
               cout<<s->items[i]<<endl;
             }

         }
 }
 int main()
 { 
   int x,Underflow,Overflow,y,z; 
   stack s;
   char ch,c;
   s.MyTop=-1; 
   cout<<"Enter String: "; 
   while(cin.get( ch ) && ch != '\n')
    {  
      PushAndTest(&Overflow,ch,&s);
    }
   return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: This is not C++, this is C borrowing std::cin and std::cout. You would be well advised to either learn the features of C++ or the I/O methods of C. Pick one and go with it.

Comment: is my explanation confusing?

Comment: No, your explanation is fine. Your code is a pile of... well, a pile. You are using pointers instead of references, you are using free functions instead of class methods, you are using parameter pointers instead of return values. This is basically mediocre C. You need to change about every single line of it to become proper C++. Maybe you can visit [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), explaining all of it is not in scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm really sorry.this is how i learned how to create a stack.

Comment: what i want to know is what i should do to my stack to work the way i want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read a string either in a character array or an object of type std::string then push its symbols in the stack and then using function pop compare each symbol of the string with the corresponding symbol in the stack.

As for your code then it shall not be compiled and contains bugs. For example the stack has no data member `MyBottom` that is used in function `PushAndTest2`

```
 void PushAndTest2(int *Overflow,char x,stack *s)
 {         
         s->items[--(s->MyBottom)]=x; 
 }
```

Also it is not clear what is the meanung of the second parameter `char x` that is not used in the body of the function (the same is valid for example for function `PushAndTest`)

In function `PopAndTest` you are trying to return an element when the stack is empty

```
 int PopAndTest(int *Underflow,char *x,stack *s)
 {
      if (Empty(s)!=1)
       *Underflow=1;
      else
       {      
         *x=s->items[(s->MyTop)--]; 
         *Underflow=0;    
       }
 }
```

Also it is not clear why did you a pointer to satck as a parameter of functions instead of using a reference.

For example function Empty could be define the following way

```
bool Empty( const stack &s )
{
   return ( s.MyTop == -1 );
}
```

**EDIT:** After you updated your code I would like to point out that some functions have undefined behaviour. For example function `PopAndTest` returns nothing while it has return type `int`

```
int PopAndTest(int *Underflow,char *x,stack *s)
 {
      if (Empty(s)!=1)
       *Underflow=1;
      else
       {      
         *x=s->items[(s->MyTop)--]; 
         *Underflow=0;    
       }
 }
```

I would define an enumeration as

```
enum class status { SUCCESS, UNDERFLOW, OVERFLOW };
```

and use it as the return value.

```
status PopAndTest( stack &s )
{
      if ( Empty( s ) ) return UNDERFLOW;

      --s->MyTop; 
      return SUCCESS;
 }
```

There is no need that the function would return an element of the stack through using parameter `char *x`. It is enough that there is function `TopAndTest`that allows to get the element in the top of the stack.

To compare characters you can use the following approach. Let assume that character array `str` contains a string and you already pushed its characters in the stack. Then you can write

```
bool is_palindrome = true;
char *p = str;

while ( *p && is_palindrome )
{
   char c;

   is_palindrome = TopAndTest( s, &c ) == status::SUCCESS && *p++ == c );
   PopAndTest( s );
}
```

I used my declaration of function TopAndTest

```
status TopAndTest( stack &s, char *c );
```

Comment: thank you.the function PushAndTest2 was something i wanted to delete before posting my program here but i forgot.sorry.

Comment: what I don't know is that how I can compare the characters since for example the first character is at the top of stack and the last character is at the bottom of stack and in order to compare these two i have to have access to the bottom of stack but i don't know how to access it(sorry I'm a beginner in using stack)

Comment: thank you so much.I wanted to give you more votes but it seems my vote is locked.

Comment: @user2589043 I uodate the lasy code snippet. You need include in the loop a call of function PopAndTest.